# jmap dump failed with file is too large

Tags: java, dump, jmap

[image]

"文件过大" in chinese means the file is too large

jdk: openjdk_1.8.0_121
os: rhel 6.5

What is the problem?

Comment: Might be a known bug - see : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145091  Note that says "Fix version: 9" - so maybe only in JDK 1.9 ?